# Executar schedule apenas em ambiente de produção

Tags: java, scheduler

Tenho um procedimento que executa todo início de mês para resetar senha de usuários inativos. Esse procedimento troca a senha do usuário e manda um e-mail notificando a nova senha.

Porém, tenho diferentes ambientes ( local, homologação e produção ) e quero que isto seja executado apenas em produção. Pensei em colocar um parametro na tabela parametro_sistema e verificar se o ambiente é de produção para poder executar o procedimento, mas periodicamente é feito o restore da base de produção nos outros ambientes e isto pode não resolver meu problema.

Alguém tem uma solução melhor para isso?

Segue o código:

```
@Schedule(dayOfMonth="1", hour="2", persistent=false)
    private void execute() throws BusinessException {
        resetarSenhas();
    }
```

Comment: Pode depender muito do pacote de frameworks que você está usando. Como se da essa configuração de ambiente? Através de profiles spring por exemplo? Se for esse o caso de uma olhada nessa resposta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406713/how-to-conditionally-enable-or-disable-scheduled-jobs-in-spring

Comment: O sistema não utiliza um framework como o Spring. Mas o controle de tokens é realizado via JWT. As requisições são via Rest.